# Issues exporting a split dataframe based on each time a certain value appears

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset, that i want to be able to split every time the values 0.0001 or 0.0002 appear.

Given this data set

```
  x       y
2.32   0.0001
2.50   0.0034
3.01   0.0045
6.05   0.0002
1.05   0.0100
6.10   0.0001
6.22   0.0022
```

I want to filter the dataframe

```
 x       y
2.32   0.0001
2.50   0.0034
3.01   0.0045

 x       y 
6.05   0.0002
1.05   0.0100

 x       y 
6.10   0.0001
6.22   0.0022
```

and be able to export the following into an excel/csv file - into separate sheets. Like so..

| x | y | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.32 | 0.0001 | 6.05 | 0.0002 |
| 2.50 | 0.0034 | 1.05 | 0.0100 |

Here is what i have tried so far

```
df_list = {f'df_{i}': g.reset_index(drop=True) 
        for i, g in df2.groupby(df2[1].eq(str(0.0001) or str(0.0002)).cumsum())}
```

which splits the dataframe as required but i am not so sure how to go about exporting into an excel file.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your output?

Comment: to export a dataframe to excel, just need this: `df.to_excel('filepath_and_name.xlsx')`....

Comment: to explain my logic, i am creating a an empty dictionary, iterate over the groups in df2 by the condition set, with previous index being dropped. with each group stored as df_i. It seems i have worked out the answer to my question - ill update.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma the logic breakdown prompted me to understand my mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
`writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        
     # Iterate over the dictionary items
     for sheet_name, df in df_list.items():
        # Write each DataFrame to a different sheet in the Excel file
          df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
        
     # Save the Excel file
      writer.save()`
```

Seems like i overlooked and forgot to iterate over the dictionary items.